# How to create a NOT NULL self-referencing foreign key in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a not-null self-referencing foreign key in sqlalchemy, something like this:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("mytable.id"), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, parent_id):
        self.parent_id = parent_id
```

There will need to be root records that are their own parent, to seed chains of relationships. The trick that I can't figure out, is how to create one of these root records, since at the moment I create a MyModel instance, I don't know yet what the DB will assign for an `id`.

One option would be to make the `parent_id` nullable, so the root records would be NULL instead of pointing to themself, but it would be preferable for this field to be NOT NULL. Is this pattern generally possible, to have a NOT NULL self-referencing foreign key in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Perhaps manually insert a row in the table for a "null entity" with `id = 0`, then the actual root entries would have `parent_id = 0` instead of `parent_id = NULL` …?

Comment: Good idea, I'll go with that